# Python Selenium Keys cannot search by CTRL+F in Browser

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to use Selenium with Python to find an athlete in a sports competition website. Since the website is very badly written I thought the easiest way to find her was not by searching for the element in HTML, but to simply make the driver press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and then type in her name.

This is the url if you want to give it a go: https://www.federdanza.it/images/gare/2019_2020/EXPORT/20210717_padiglione1/6052-coppie_danzestd_senior3(55-60)_as/index.htm

Up to now, I have managed to type into the DuckDuckGo search bar, but I do not understand why I cannot type into the Chrome search bar.

As you can see, the code at the moment is trying to search for "RUG".

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

PATH = "/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

time.sleep(10)
#Waiting for the web page to load

action1 = ActionChains(driver)
action2 = ActionChains(driver)
action3 = ActionChains(driver)


action1.key_down(Keys.COMMAND).send_keys('F').key_up(Keys.COMMAND)
action2.send_keys('R').send_keys('U').send_keys('G')
action3.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

action1.perform()
action2.perform()
action3.perform()
```

I even asked the program to tell me in Console each time an action has been performed successfully and it seems to work fine, even though there is no response in the browser.
Could it be because I am using a Mac and keys are slightly different? On Windows, the search command is invoked by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> while on Mac is invoked by <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. What else could I try?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Actionschains you could try the `pyautogui` module. Searching a word would look something like this:

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl','f') 
pyautogui.typewrite('Your keyword')    
pyautogui.hotkey('Return')
```

More information here: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/